# Spring jpa Entity is not a managed type

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I've tried a couple of solutions from other questions but none of them fixed the problem.

Typos shouldn't be the problem since my ide highlights the package names properly.

Here's my setup:

Entity:

```
package sh.owl.hootament.backend.database.entities;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Creators")
public class CreatorEntity {    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String id;

    @Column
    private String username;

    @Column
    private String email;

    // Getters and settters
    [...]
}
```

Repository:

```
package sh.owl.hootament.backend.database.repositories;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "creators")
public interface CreatorEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<CreatorEntity, String> {
}
```

Configuration Class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSpringConfigured
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "sh.owl.hootament.backend.database.repositories")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "sh.owl.hootament.backend.database.entities")
@ComponentScan("sh.owl.hootament.*")
public class SpringConfiguration {
}
```

Index Controller to test:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @Autowired
    private CreatorEntityRepository creatorEntityRepository;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model) {
        creatorEntityRepository.saveAndFlush(new CreatorEntity());
    }
}
```

And spring crashes with the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class sh.owl.hootament.backend.database.entities.CreatorEntity
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:210) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:70) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:68) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:153) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:100) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:82) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:199) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

Edit, added gradle file:

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.5.7.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

dependencies {
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-hal-browser')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
compile('org.springframework.session:spring-session')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
compile("org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4:2.1.3.RELEASE")

compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')

testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
}
```

Comment: Check for typos.

Comment: @Entity.. whats the package?

Comment: Package name is: sh.owl.hootament.backend.database.entities;

Comment: is it javax.persistence.Entity?

Comment: Ah! I'm using the hibernate `@Entity` attribute. I've edited the post to add the gradle (generated via start.spring.io) file. Am I missing a lib since `javax.persistence.Entity` doesn't exist?

Comment: It comes with JPA dependencies you have included so it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I just needed to reindex all libraries since it couldn't find `javax.persistence.Entity` and used the hibernate one instead.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see @SpringBootApplication on the Config class.

If you have some other class with the main method and @SpringBootApplication.

Try moving @EnableJpaRepositories and @EntityScan on you main class.

Else if your Config class is the main class add @SpringBootApplication on it